# angular2 webpack unresolved variable webstorm

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to install Webpack on my angular2 project.

All is ok but webstorm detect unresolved variables in my webpack.config.ts file.
Here is a part of the code :

```
module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {

var config = {};


if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
}
else if (isTest) {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
}
else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
}
```

devtool is an unresolved variable for webstorm. I dont know why.
I have the same problem in this file with :

```
config.entry
config.output
config.module
config.resolve
config.plugins
config.devServer
```

But the project is working. Ty for ur help !!!